# Umwandeln or sich umwandeln?

Tags: verb-usage

In conversation with 2 native German speakers, I said:

> Die Wärme wandelt in Elektrizität, Licht, mechanische Arbeit und so weiter um.

and they said that it had to be reflexive:

> Die Wärme wandelt **sich** in Elektrizität, Licht, mechanische Arbeit und so weiter um.

However, I find in Duden under umwandeln:
1.a. zu etwas anderem machen, die Eigenschaften von etwas, auch jemandem verändern

Beispiel: mechanische Energie in Elektrizität umwandeln

How does my usage differ from that in Duden and when would one use or not use reflexivity? Do the same considerations apply to wandeln?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between your usage and the Duden usage is in the roles of the subject and object of the verb. This is different from the English "to change".

> **A** *(subject)* wandelt **B** *(acc. object)* in **C** *(preposition* in *with acc.)* um.
> Die Sonne wandelt Wasserstoff in Helium um. 
> Eine Dampfmaschine wandelt Wärme in mechanische Energie um.
> Ein Generator wandelt mechanische Energie in Elektrizität um.

"A" is the agent, "B" is what is converted, "C" is the product of the conversion.

If you don't wish to mention the agent, the reflexive form is an alternative:

> **B** *(subject)* wandelt sich in **C** *(preposition* in *with acc.)* um.
> Kernfusion: Wasserstoff wandelt sich in Helium um.
> Wärme wandelt sich in mechanische Energie um.
> Mechanische Energie wandelt sich im Generator *(dative)* in Elektrizität *(accusative)* um.

You could also use the passive voice, which seems actually more appropriate than the reflexive form if the change is externally induced:

> Wärme wird von einer Dampfmaschine in mechanische Energie umgewandelt.

"Wandeln" has several meanings, but one of them is similar to "umwandeln", and in that meaning is is used in the same grammatical way.

> Eine Dampfmaschine wandelt Wärme in mechanische Energie.
> Das Aussehen des Waldes wandelt sich mit den Jahreszeiten.
> Wärme wird von einer Dampfmaschine in mechanische Energie gewandelt.

Comment: A remarkably lucid and informative response. Much appreciated.

Comment: „If you don't wish to mention the agent, the reflexive form is an alternative“ - disagree with that. In that case it’s mandatory to use the _passive voice_. The _reflexive_ is used when the agent and the object are identical, something or someone changing _itselt_.

Answer (score 2):

The verb "umwandeln" needs 3 partners in a sentence: One subject and two objects, both objects in accusative case, one of them also with the word "in":

> Etwas(1) wandelt etwas(2) in etwas(3) um.

1. The first "etwas" is the subject. Who does the change?
2. The second "etwas" (without "in") is the original thing that will be changed. What was is before the change?
3. The third "etwas" (with "in") is the resulting thing after it was changed. What is is after the change?

> Säure wandelt Metall in Salz um.

1. *Säure* (acid) does the change.
2. The changing thing was *Metall* (metal) before the change.
3. The changing thing is *Salz* (salt) after the change.

All 3 components must be there.

This is wrong:

> Die Wärme wandelt in Elektrizität (...) um.

Here we have only the parts 1 and 3, but 2 is missing:

1. *Die Wärme* (heat) does the change.
2. ??? What was the changing thing before the change???
3. The changing thing is *Elektrizität* (electricity) after the change.

The solution is, that heat turns itself into electricity:

> Die Wärme wandelt **Wärme** in Elektrizität (...) um.

But instead of having the same thing twice in the sentence you use a pronoun that refers to the first thing. It must be in the correct case (accusative):

> Die Wärme wandelt **sich** in Elektrizität (...) um.

But when you say this with the pronoun, then you don't really mean, that the heat does the change. What you really mean is, that something, that is not mentioned, does the change. Maybe a machine like a generator. So, when you say "Die Wärme wandelt sich in Elektrizität um" then you really mean:

> Irgendetwas wandelt Wärme in Elektrizität um.